# Define layout size in JAVA depending of the screen size (android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to display a dialog when I click on a button. I've done a custom dialog like that :

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(300, 450);
dialog.show();
```

As you can see, I define the size of the layout with window.setLayout in java, because it doesn't work on xml for the dialog (and I can't put the dialog theme on the activity). I would like to set a layout size in java depending of the screen size as for xml with layout-large and xlarge (as I explained, I can't use the xml to define the layout depending on the screen size).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it on the `dimens.xml` file on the `values` folder. You can specify a values folder for different screen sizes like this:

```
values-w820dp
```

and the dimens.xml file example:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="dialog_height">64dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dialog_width">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicTransition/res/values-w820dp/dimens.html) you have more info about it.

Then on your code you can access it like this

```
int dialogHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_height)
int dialogWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dialog_width)
```

`getResources().getDimension()` will resolve the right dimension from the right folder based on the device automatically.

Here you have some common configurations:

> - 320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
> - 480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
> - 600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
> - 720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's a good idea. But can you tell me what name I have to give to the values directory to suit exactly (if possible) with the layout, layout-large and layout-xlarge directories?

Comment: @Jey10 it dependes on what devices are you targeting, if you want to change the dialog size if it´s a tablet for example, with w820dp you could target devices between 7" and 10".

Comment: I would like to target approximatively the screens around 5", around 7" and more than 8.5"

Comment: @Jay10 Update my answer with some screen sizes for you. I think you should add w480dp and w820dp for targeting those screen sizes.

Comment: Thank you very much, so last question, to define phones between 4 and 5 (or 6), I choose 320 or 480dp?

Comment: @Jey10 320dp should make it

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution , i have been use it with costume layout

1. get screen size (width and height)
2. set it to the dialog .

**Here is the Code**

```
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_customer);
            try {
                LinearLayout lytdialog = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog);
                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int height = size.y;
                int width = size.x;
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = lytdialog.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = width;
                layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                lytdialog.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dialog.show();
        }
```

Happy Coding